# What is -u flag on cURL actually doing?

Tags: curl

I'm looking at Stripe's cURL example for getting info on an event.

They have me do:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/events/evt_123 \
   -u sk_test_somekey:
```

The documentation for cURL states that `-u` does `USER:PASSWORD`.

When I tried sending this as `-d` or as a query `?`, Stripe's API says that I'm missing a header. This doesn't seem right.

I don't understand the lack of password after the username, either. If I send that cURL without the `:`, I am prompted for a password. Hitting enter (no characters inputted), gets me the expected response.

So, what exactly is `-u` doing so I can imitate this call in my code?

Comment: leaving out the password (no colon) will have curl prompt for it. With just a colon it means a zero-length password.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`curl -u` encodes the `username:password` string into a base-64 string which is passed in the `Authorization` header, like so:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: text/html
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

This isn't easy to skim, but **it's not encryption** either. Anyone with a [base 64 decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64/decoder) can see the username and password, so make sure you set up HTTPS with a modern version of TLS.

Your HTTP library probably has a function that does this for you.