# Phoenix/Elixir - cURL works, but HTTPoison fails

Tags: curl, elixir, phoenix-framework, httpoison, agile-crm

In my Phoenix app, I am trying to use the HTTPoison HTTP client (https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/api-reference.html) to make a post request to the AgileCRM API. I was able to use cURL to make a successful request, but my attempt to replicate it in Phoenix is failing with a 401 `UNAUTHORIZED` error.

My successful cURL:

```
$ curl https://domain.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/search/email \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-d 'email_ids=["contact@test.com"]' \
-u admin@test.com:api_key
```

which returns status `200` and the requested data.

My failing HTTPoison:

```
url = "https://domain.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/search/email"
body = Poison.encode!(%{"body": "email_ids=['contact@test.com']"})
headers = [{"Accept", "application/json"}, {"Authorization", "admin@test.com:api_key"}]

response = HTTPoison.post!(url, body, headers)

IO.inspect response
```

which returns

```
%HTTPoison.Response{body: "<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<title>401 UNAUTHORIZED</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: UNAUTHORIZED</h1>\n</body></html>\n",
headers: [{"X-TraceUrl", "/appstats/details?time=1509129565372&type=json"},
{"WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"agilecrm\""},
{"Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"},
{"X-Cloud-Trace-Context", "8de994n2tbu2o356891bc3e6"},
{"Date", "Fri, 27 Oct 2017 18:39:25 GMT"}, {"Server", "Google Frontend"},
{"Content-Length", "200"}],
request_url: "https://domain.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts/search/email", status_code: 401}
```

From the message, I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that the issue is with the authorization data. My understanding was that the `-u` flag in a cURL is the equivalent of adding an `Authorization` header, but perhaps not?

HTTPoison also allows for an `options` parameter, and one of the options (ha!) is ":proxy_auth - proxy authentication {User, Password} tuple", but passing `[proxy_auth: {"admin@test.com", "api_key"}]` produces the same result.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent of `curl -u` is the [`basic_auth` option of `hackney`](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/5b51fb82547dd3a492aaac5d63f7aa1ada1e65cf/src/hackney_request.erl#L37), not HTTPoison's `proxy_auth`. You can use it like this:

```
HTTPoison.post!(url, body, headers, hackney: [basic_auth: {"admin@test.com", "api_key"}])
```

Comment: Perfect! Dogbert, you've saved me again.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `curl -u` does more, check this answer: [What is -u flag on cURL actually doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442816/what-is-u-flag-on-curl-actually-doing).

It encodes your user:password into base 64  string  and adds `Basic` prefix.

You should send a header like this

```
Authorization: Basic base64 encoded string
```

Comment: Thanks - the accepted answer worked for me, but this is really useful to know (I was not aware).