# How to transform CURL request to Httpoison request in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: curl, elixir, phoenix-framework, httpoison

I'm trying to transform CURL request with HTTPoison in Elixir Phoenix.
When I run CURL request commend, It work fine.I got "415 Unsupported media type" error when I try with HTTPoison.

[Phoenix/Elixir - cURL works, but HTTPoison fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981804/phoenix-elixir-curl-works-but-httpoison-fails)

Here is my CURL request

```
curl -u "user:password" -i -H "Accept:application/json" -X POST -d
 "amount=100&method=0&type=bank&receiver=CCC&info1=hello" 
 http://00.000.000.00:8080/services/id/999999111999/calculate
```

Here is my Httpoison request

```
url = "myurl"
orderid = "myorderid"
headers = ["Accept", "application/json"]
request_body = '{"type" : "bank", 
         "method" : 0,
         "amount" : #{amount},
                 "receiver" : "CCC"
         "info1" : #{orderid}}'
dicoba = HTTPoison.post(url, headers, request_body, hackney: [basic_auth: {"#{user}", "#password"}]) |> IO.inspect
```

Comment: I doubt `HTTPoison` supports _lists_ in `request_body` parameter and yours is indeed a list instead of string. Single quotes in Elixir do not what you expect them to do. Use `~s` sigil instead.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/elixir/

Answer (score 2):

The curl request is in the content type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, but your HTTPoison request is, well, malformed. You passed a charlist to the request body, where HTTPoison expects a binary, and you didn't specify the request's content type.

To create a **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** request body, you can use the function `URI.encode_query/1`.

```
url = "http://00.000.000.00:8080/services/id/999999111999/calculate"
payload = %{
  "amount" => 100,
  "method" => 0,
  "type" => "bank",
  "receiver" => "CCC",
  "info1" => "hello"
}
request_body = URI.encode_query(payload)
headers = [
  {"Accept", "application/json"}, 
  {"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"}
]
dicoba = HTTPoison.post(url, request_body, headers, hackney: [basic_auth: {"#{user}", "#password"}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got this error message with 400 status.
```body: "{\"errorMessage\":\"COUNT_VIOLATED_ERROR\",\"errorCode\":\"99999999\"}"
```

Comment: What does **COUNT_VIOLATED_ERROR** mean?

Comment: @Aetherus I think the `request_body comes` before the `headers`
`HTTPoison.post(url, request_body, headers, hackney: [basic_auth: {"#{user}", "#password"}]) `

Comment: @Aetherus awesome,Other thank that,  I like your solution, it helped